# Environment variables in Fish

Tags: bash, environment-variables, fish

I need  to use a program called Kpax, the "installation" process consist in this:

```
(for bash users, edit ~/.bashrc)
   export KPAX_ROOT=/home/dritchie/kpax       <-  substitute the proper pathname here.

   export PATH=${PATH}:${KPAX_ROOT}/bin
```

I'm using Garuda with fish shell, if I run Kpax using bash works great, the problem is that I need to run Kpax from a php file and every time I use `shell_exec()` this appear in the error_log:

```
kpax: command not found
```

Is there a way to replicate the thing with the environment variables in fish as in bash?

Comment: You'll use the [`set`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html) command to create the environment variable (instead of `export`), and the [`fish_add_path`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html) command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fish shell 3.2 or later, you can just run:

```
fish_add_path /home/dritchie/kpax/bin
```

substituting in your home directory.

You can run this once at the command line, or add it to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`; either way it will be remembered. Here's documentation for [fish_add_path](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html?highlight=fish_add_path).

You might still need the KPAX_ROOT environment variable, however, so you might still need to set -U that one.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html?highlight=environment

You'll need to use the set command to set the variables and explicitly export them.

According to https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html?highlight=configuration (search deep in the document for "Startup (where's .bashrc)" the file you need to edit is ~/.config/fish/config.fish)

So putting those two together, add the following to the end of your existing ~/.config/fish/config.fish (or just create a file containing only the following if that doesn't already exist):

```
set -gx KPAX_ROOT <your path to KPAX installation>
set -gx PATH $PATH "$KPAX_ROOT"/bin
```

Alternatively, it might be even easier to just create the needed variables as "Universal":

```
set -U KPAX_ROOT <path to KPAX installation>
set -U PATH $PATH "$KPAX_ROOT"/bin
```

(You should only have to execute this once and it should update fish for eternity on your behalf according to the documentation).

I don't have and haven't used fish, but hopefully these references to the fish manual and the suggestions I provide will get you where you need.